# how to understand "{{{{{0}}}}}".format("test")

Tags: python

`The code in python 3.9.1`

```py
print( "{{{{{0}}}}}".format("test") )  # output:{{test}}
```

**Confusion**

> How my python understand so many {}?(And {} sometimes can mean set)
>
> Some good examples is needed!

Comment: Using `format`, `{{` is a single escaped `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `format`, `{{` is a single escaped `{`. And `}}` is an escaped `}`. So you have `{0}` (which is "test") surrounded by escaped `{` and `}`, twice.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax , which says:

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.